# Exponents and Log properties

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, logarithms, exponentiation

This is part of a proof I am working on.

> So on one line, I needed to show that
> $$2^{\Bigg(\cfrac{\ln\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(2)}\Bigg)} =\frac{1}{n}$$

That was $2$ to the power of   $\ \ \cfrac{\ln\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(2)}$

Now I tried to use the log/exponent cancellation techniques to no avail. I think there is a property I am missing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

$$\frac{\log_a b}{\log_a c} = \log_c b$$

Hence:

$$2^{\Bigg(\cfrac{\ln\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(2)}\Bigg)}=2^{\textstyle\log_2\frac{1}{n}} =\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: @Bachelier : 2 things to note re player3236's answer (1) his formula is distinct from $\log A - \log B = \log \left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$. (2) His formula can be proven by noticing that $a^{[(\log_a c) \times (\log_c b)]} = [a^{(\log_a c)}]^ {(\log_c b)} = c^{(\log_c b)} = b = a^{(\log_a b)}.$ Therefore, $(\log_a c) \times (\log_c b) = (\log_a b).$

Comment: or $\log_a b = \log_a \left(c^{\textstyle\log_c b}\right) = \log_c b \log_a c$

Comment: elegant alternative

Comment: That was it. Change of base formula. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, using $A^B=e^{B\ln A}$, we have

$$\large 2^{\left(\frac{\ln\frac{1}{n}}{\ln 2}\right)}=e^{\left(\frac{\ln\frac{1}{n}}{\ln 2}\ln 2\right)}=e^{\ln \frac1n}=\frac1n$$